Best solution to store scenes
I'm using Blender to make a comic that takes place in the same room, like a play.
Currently, I use the timeline to store the pose and position of each character. But I was wondering if this is the best solution or if there is another way (Integrated or add-on) to store each static scene so I can edit them later if needed.
Thanks for your help!


You can add new scenes in the top right of the screen. Scenes can be thought of as snapshots of the contents of your viewport. The setting you'll most likely want is Full Copy, as this will duplicate the existing contents and make the resulting copy independent of the original. You could then arrange each scene's contents as you like, and you can switch between different scenes you've created by accessing the Scene icon itself (to the left of the word "Scene"), which will expose a dropdown containing a list of all the scenes currently available.

Tbh i think using one scene and keyframes as the author already does is simpler to use.

I also use your technique.  I would edit your answer to mention that you then want to delete the animations on the Full Copy scene to reanimate anew.

Thanks a lot, I'll have a look
